# Getting MS Date Value in SQL

Tags: sql

Is there a way to retrieve the date code value - like how, in Excel, 4/27/2015 is represented as 42121 - in SQL? My search-fu has shown me not much more than CONVERT, but I can't see a date format that returns just that integer value.

Comment: Which database tech are you using, please tag the question accordingly. It is possible to convert a date to epochtime, as is demonstrated here https://www.epochconverter.com/.

Comment: @AdamQuark Greetings, thanks and other social niceties are neither required nor expected on [so]. Nobody will be offended by the lack of a 'Hello'. I have edited out the extraneous explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
USE MASTER
GO
DECLARE @InDate DATE='20150427';
SELECT @InDate,DATEADD(DD,-42121,@InDate)AS BASE_DATE,DATEDIFF(DD,'18991230',@InDate)AS DATE_DIFF
```

I suspect, in Excel the value 42121 is calculated as a difference between '2015-04-27' and predefined "zero-date"(most probably, '1899-12-30'), so you can try to use DATEDIFF to calculate it

Comment: Excel actually uses January 1, 1900 as its base date - but for any dates after March 1st 1900 you won't see that as it inserts a non existent day.  https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2006/06/16/my-first-billg-review/

Comment: Excel has a "Date System", see: [Date systems in Excel](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/date-systems-in-excel-e7fe7167-48a9-4b96-bb53-5612a800b487#:~:text=Change%20the%20default%20date%20system&text=Click%20File%20%3E%20Options.&text=%2C%20and%20then%20click%20Excel%20Options,clear%20Use%201904%20date%20system.)  the starting date is 01-01-1900 or 01-01-1904

Comment: I had thought there might be a convenient statement or date format for use with CAST or CONVERT, but I guess not. Okie dokie, I'll go with the DATEADD/DATEDIFF route. Thanx, Sergey, Martin and Luuk!